# Invite Facebook friends error

Tags: facebook

I created a page tab like and win application. The plugin that Facebook provides for inviting friends doesn't seem to work anymore. Is there an error with the plugin?

This is the app: https://www.facebook.com/mees.melky/app_196218193879130

Kind Regards,
Mark

Comment: What is the plugin? Error message?

Comment: It's the plugin were you can select friends and they then get a notification with a link to the app.

Answer (score 1):

try this it has helped me. copy it in ur html .

http://www.9lessons.info/2012/07/facebook-invite-friends-api.html#comment-form